# How to compass compile in rake task

Tags: ruby, rake, sass, compass-sass

I use rake to prepare files for development.
But I can't compile my sass files with compass

```
  desc "Compile to compressed css"
  task :compile_compressed do
    #Go to the compass project directory
    Dir.chdir File.join( ENV['base_path'], CONF['dir']['compass'] ) do |dir|
      file_compass_config = "/path/to/some/different/config.rb"

      system "compass compile -c #{file_compass_config} --force"
    end
  end
```

I'm using rvm with a gemset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from the question actually works.

Probably it was caused beacuse the script was not in he rvm gemset where compass was installed.